# ObjectForKey - How to check if ObjectForKey has @"String"

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, xcode4

I have this line...

```
 if(![[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"special_trip"] isEqualToString:@""]) {
```

Everything is cool.. But I special_trip has many informations, so I want to take for example only the results which have the string Airport in : 1:Airport, Packet

I just want to take those results which contain Airport in the whole string.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Sorry for confusing.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but can't you just do `isEqualToString:@"Airport"` if that's what you want to check?

Comment: if([[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"special_trip"]){//has string}else{//no value}. provide [[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"special_trip"] output to find your string

Comment: I did that Amy, but special_trip may have this:

1:Airport, packet
2:Airport
3:Airport, packet, letter

Comment: Thanks guys.. I did this:


        if([[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"special_trip"] rangeOfString:@"port"].location != NSNotFound) {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
if([myString rangeOfString:@"Airport"].location != NSNotFound ) {
    // myString contains Airport
}
```

Comment: I start to have the idea... If I get the result, I'll tell you. Thanks

Comment: At the end it ended like this:


        if([[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"special_trip"] rangeOfString:@"port"].location != NSNotFound) {


Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the function

```
NSArray *filteredArray = [myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Take a look at the [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html).

Comment: Thanks buddy, I found the answer. But I read something new. Really apreciated.

Answer (score 1):

if i got you correctly ..... why dont you use this simple line -

```
if([[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"special_trip"] isEqualToString:@"Airport"])
{
   //
}
```

and if i am wrong :-( please let me know what is the problem exactly.

Thank you!

Comment: The problem is that the key special trip has lots of infos.. Like this:

1:Airport, Packet

Comment: if([[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"special_trip"] rangeOfString:@"port"].location != NSNotFound) {


This is working :)

Comment: so what - if([[[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"special_trip"] isEqualToString:@"Airport"])  this is filtering the string.... and if you want only @"Airport" this will definitely work...... well congrats you have solved your problem... :-)

Comment: Like the example: 

1:Airport,Packet is a full string with @"Airport,Packet" that is the value.. Not just Airport, so the statement pass cause it is not equal to Airport.

Comment: oh ok ....... now your question has been completed.... sorry i didn't get you, you did not write the full details in your question.

Comment: you wrote @"Airport" and @"Packet" separately, it made me confuse.

Comment: Yeah, as I read it again it sounds weird... Sorry but French ate my brain and English is weak.. But thanks.